# SQL Server Return End of Month Stock from the last 12 Months with Slowly Changing Dimensions (SCD) Type 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a SCD Type 2 Table, where I want to find End of Month Stock for the last 12 Months, but I'm having a really hard time to make it happen.
Anyone can please help??

**Below you can find the table structure:**

| Date | Product | Supplier | Stock on Hand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20220824 | 19789063 | 152254 | 27 |
| 20220607 | 19789063 | 152254 | 28 |
| 20220514 | 19789063 | 152254 | 28 |
| 20220507 | 19789063 | 152254 | 26 |
| 20220504 | 19789063 | 152254 | 27 |
| 20220502 | 19789063 | 152254 | 24 |
| 20220427 | 19789063 | 152254 | 29 |
| 20220423 | 19789063 | 152254 | 30 |
| 20220422 | 19789063 | 152254 | 20 |
| 20211216 | 19789063 | 152254 | 0 |
| 20211214 | 19789063 | 152254 | 1 |
| 20211209 | 19789063 | 152254 | 0 |
| 20211208 | 19789063 | 152254 | 1 |
| 20211207 | 19789063 | 152254 | 3 |
| 20211206 | 19789063 | 152254 | 6 |
| 20211204 | 19789063 | 152254 | 13 |
| 20211203 | 19789063 | 152254 | 14 |
| 20211201 | 19789063 | 152254 | 15 |
| 20211126 | 19789063 | 152254 | 14 |
| 20210712 | 19789063 | 152254 | 0 |

**Expected Output:**

| Date | Product | Supplier | Stock on Hand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20220731 | 19789063 | 152254 | 28 |
| 20220630 | 19789063 | 152254 | 28 |
| 20220531 | 19789063 | 152254 | 28 |
| 20220430 | 19789063 | 152254 | 29 |
| 20220331 | 19789063 | 152254 | 0 |
| 20220228 | 19789063 | 152254 | 0 |
| 20220131 | 19789063 | 152254 | 0 |
| 20211231 | 19789063 | 152254 | 0 |
| 20211130 | 19789063 | 152254 | 14 |

Comment: Please don't link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Comment: if you are looking for end of month, maybe try using the [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)  function

Comment: Jocohan, I know that function and I've used as a variable to try to retrieve the EOM stock for last 12M, but with no success. the problem is to get the stock available related to the report period